# Semi-colon terminates storing string to datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

So i have this ndb datasore class :

```
class Messages(ndb.Model):
  message = ndb.StringProperty()
  emailid = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)    
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

  @classmethod
  def query_book(cls,key):
    return cls.query(ancestor=key).order(-cls.date)
```

and when I try to save the string given below to the 'message' StringProperty:

```
"class asd
{
public void fun()
{
    printf ("hello world!!!");

}

}    "
```

only the part up to the semicolon gets stored into the datastore. If I don't put the semicolon the the entire string gets stored.I should mention that the above string is input by the user. The semicolon and other special characters may appear anywhere. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I have no idea what this is, but that sounds hilarious. Good luck

Comment: Thanks... Hoping someone has had this issue before and solved it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its works fine for me on both developer and production environment.
You said that you got this data from user input, so look for problem there. NDB works just fine with this.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class _Foo(ndb.Model):
  message = ndb.StringProperty()
  emailid = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)    
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

  @classmethod
  def query_book(cls,key):
    return cls.query(ancestor=key).order(-cls.date)

key = ndb.Key(_Foo, '1')
message = """class asd
{
public void fun()
{
    printf ("hello world!!!");

}

}    """
f = _Foo(key=key)

f.message = message
f.put()

assert key.get().message == message  # no error here, means they are equal
```

Comment: You are right. It's a problem with my HTTP POST request. I'm sending the complete data. But only seem to be getting up to the semi-colon